# Using UITableViewController in a navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm new to iOS, but I know the basis. I want to host 3 `UITableViewController` in a `UITabBarController` using the `storyboard`.

I dragged a `UITableViewController` from the object list(?)  and control dragged creating a seguel. Now the tab shows successfully the table view controller.

The issue is the rows are taking the space of the status bar. So I want a navigation bar(?) there, with a title. Since I'm new to iOS I don't know the following:

Given the fact that `UITabBarController` is the first controller ever, the hosted `UITableViewController` should **not** have a **back** button, obviously. So is it correct to use a navigation bar to display a title (and possible add/edit buttons)

If so, I tried dragging the **Navigation Bar** but it doesn't work.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: try drag a new UINavigation Controller to your storyboard, set a title and put all  ur current stuff into it, and link ur Navigation Controller with ur tab item in ur Tabbar Controller, you can hide the back button for ur Navigation bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps
[image]

actually it is done for another answer. but it will be handy to u too

Comment: I'm accepting your answer since the visual was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You will want to add in 3 `UINavigationController`s. Have each tab in the tab bar controller segue to a different navigation controller. Then set the root view controller for each navigation controller to one of the table view controllers.